# Why is my DropDownList in asp.net not refreshing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms, refresh

I have a simple DropDownList on my asp.net webpage:

It looks like this:

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="FriendList" runat="server" 
                     EnableViewState="False" Height="30px" Width="10%"  
                     OnTextChanged="FriendListSwitch" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" />
            </Triggers>
            <--!The button is a stub, I actually need to load it from the codebehind-->

       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then I have the codebehind like this:

```
void OnRosterItem(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.iq.roster.RosterItem item)
{
    FriendList.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("{0}", item.Jid.User), ""));
    FriendList.DataBind();
}
```

While debugging I can see that 'FriendList' is being filled, and also that 'btnSend' is being clicked.

Yet my DropDownList is not refilling itself, it just stays empty, why is it not refreshing?

Edit: I'd rather remove the button and replace it with

```
 void OnRosterEnd(object sender)
     {
         UpdatePanel5.Update();
     }
```

But then I keep getting

```
The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'X' before Render.
```

Solved, the DataBind() only worked inside a Page_Load for me.

Answer (score 1):

The button 'btnSend' should be inside the update panel

Comment: I've got multiple updatepanels working with the trigger outside of the panel working as intended, and I tried putting it inside the panel, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try using OnSelectedIndexChanged event instead of OnTextChanged

Comment: Actually that part of the box is working, I tested it with preset values

Answer (score 0):

If you need the button to update the dropdown then it needs to be in the update panel

If you need the dropdown list to be the trigger then asyncpostback trigger needs to have the control id of the dropdown list

Comment: The button (or rather something from codebehind) should update it.
And just putting it in between isn't working.

Comment: why cant you put the button in the update panel? if it needs to be invisible initially just set the Visible property to false. If you want to update the data in the dropdown from the button, then the button needs to be in the update panel

Comment: I did put the button inside the update panel, it unfortunately changes nothing and the problem still persists...

Comment: Yes I have added a script manager and it is working on several other updatepanels.

Comment: you have said that you have added the button to the update panel, but i dont see it in your question. can you update your question to reflect the button in the update panel so we can troubleshoot correctly